# Wearable notifications can not be seen on wearable simulator

Tags: android, wear-os

I have created a simple app. Which will a notification for both handheld device and wearable. Below is code to create notification

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int notificationId = 001;
    // Build intent for notification content
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("Location")
            .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

    // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I could see notification on phone but wearable simulator does not show any notification.

I have followed following steps

1. Created wearable simulator
2. Installed android wear app from Play store. Connected phone to desktop through USB
3. Used "Connect to emulator" option from "Android wear" app. Demo cards are seen properly on wearable simulator.
4. Installed my app (above code) on phone. Triggered notification. Notification is shown on phone but not on simulator. I observed logs but no exception it thrown

Am I missing something here.
Mini Sdk level for app:8
Target Sdk for app :21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and the solution was in **Settings -> Security -> Notification access**,  check **Android Wear** to allow it to read all notifications.

Comment: Thanks !! I will check and let you know result. Thanks again :)